# Implement dummy registration with Django

Tags: python, django, mobile, registration, backend

I'm using Django to develop the backend of my mobile app. I noticed some app have an 'one tap registration" functionality. User can just tap a button and a user id is generated for him, he can upload his data to his account already. Later when he has time, he can update info like username, password or email.

I'm wondering how can I do this with Django, I check django-user-accounts or the native Django.contrib.auth, but it seems they always require username or email at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning on using `django.contrib.auth`, you can write your own [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) in Django 1.5. The example listed in the docs would work for your use-case.

You don't need to extend `AbstractBaseUser`, but if you do, it expects a `USERNAME_FIELD` value. Alternatively you can use any kind of model you want, but without a `USERNAME_FIELD` convenient methods like `login()` and `logout()` and `authenticate()` may break.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your comments. Yes, I'm thinking about using dummy_username at first. Then if updating username is not possible, I may try to just create a new user and transfer the existing user's data to the new user. Hope it's not too complicated. ;) cheers.